# How should the order of application of rotation transformation be interpreted (in PowerPoint)?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, rotations, rigid-transformation

For a university assignment, I have a question about rotating a picture in PowerPoint. In PowerPoint, a picture can have four transformations. Rotate right (90°), rotate left (90°), flip horizontally and flip vertically. Let's call them $R(r)$, $R(l)$, $F(v)$ and $F(h)$ for short.

We are then asked to compute the matrix multiplication for every pair of possible transformations. For example, $R(r)*R(r)$ or $R(r)*F(h)$.

All of that seems fairly simple to me, but they specified something in the question I don't understand.

> $R(r)*R(l)$ is **read from right to left** as "rotate left" then "rotate
>   the result right", because Powerpoint transformations are performed in
>   *world coordinates*.

Can someone explain to me why I would read that left to right? And does that mean when I multiply the matrices together I would, in fact, do $R(l)*R(r)$ when asked to do $R(r)*R(l)$?

Why would world co-ordinates effect this?

Would I read all transformations as left to right or just some?

Comment: Cross site exact duplicate (SO) [Rotation matrices - Order of transformations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43510359/4975230)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of “world coordinates,” whatever that might mean in the context of PowerPoint, doesn’t really have anything to do with why the transformation matrices are applied right to left. If you write the coordinates of a point as a *column* vector, then you left-multiply it by a matrix to get the transformed point. If you want to chain another transformation onto that, you put it on the left side, so the chains build right-to-left. If you write the coordinates of a point as a *row* vector, on the other hand, then you multiply on the right by the transformation matrices, and chains of transformations build left-to-right.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, the fact its world coordinates doesn't really matter, its just when you're chaining together matrix transformations you calculate it from right to left? 
E.G
[ 0 , 1  ]   [  -1 , 0 ] X
[ -1 , 0 ]    [ 0 ,  1  ]  would be calculated from the right to the left.

Comment: @reemq8 Pretty much. Hagen’s answer is a good way to look at it: equate function composition with matrix multiplication. For column vectors, you left-multiply to apply an transformation, so successive ones stack to the left. For row vectors, you right-multiply, so they stack to the right.

Answer (score 4):

The product $AB$ of matrices is the effect of applying $A$ after applying $B$, simply because we write the "effect" of a matrix $A$ on a vector $v$ as $Av$ (i.e., the convention is to work with column vectors). Thus $(AB)v=A(Bv)$ is $A$ applied to $Bv$. Note that this convention matches the usual notation for (nested) functions: $\log(\sin(x))$ is the logarithm function applied to the result from applying the sine function to $x$.

Of course, the rules for computing the product of matrices are just right for this convention. Or, if one wanted $AB$ to stand for "first apply $A$, then apply $B$", one would use row vectors instead and write "$A$ aplied to $v$" as $vA$ - which is very uncommon (and in effect just means that one works with the transposed matrices, relative to the usual convention).

Comment: A fine answer, but it doesn't answer the question regarding world coordinates. That question is probably better asked in someplace dedicated to computer graphics, though, as conventions in that field may seem a bit odd to a mathematician. I might have attempted it myself, but it's been too long since last time I looked at this sort of thing, so I'd probably mess it up.

Comment: I think that they specified "world coordinates" as an attempt to reinforce that the second transformation is applied to the result of the first transformation on the input - pixel coordinates in the image coordinate system - maybe in contrast to something like a crop operation that leaves the image filling the same frame, which _could_ be regarded as changing the pixel coordinates within the image coordinates and then filling with interpolated pixels.